# Why is $arr[] = 'x' faster than $arr[0] = 'x'

Tags: php, performance, php-7.2

I have the following:

```
# a.php
for($i=1; $i<=5000000; $i++) {
    $arr = [];
    for($f = 1; $f <= 5; $f++) {
        $arr[$f] = 'a'; # <-- I am passing an index manually
    }
}
```

And this:

```
# b.php
for($i=1; $i<=5000000; $i++) {
    $arr = [];
    for($f = 1; $f <= 5; $f++) {
        $arr[] = 'a'; # <-- Note that I am not passing an index manually
    }
}
```

Why is **`b.php`** code faster than **`a.php`** code?...

In **`b.php`** I am not passing an index manually, so PHP calculates it (isn't this slower?), and **`a.php`** passes a defined index to that array, so I'm confused about this

Used npm's gnomon package for time measurement

```
~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.0981s   

     Total   1.0985s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.1350s   

     Total   1.1358s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.1664s   

     Total   1.1668s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.1105s   

     Total   1.1108s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.1074s   

     Total   1.1078s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.0969s   

     Total   1.0973s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.0872s   

     Total   1.0875s

~/$ php a.php | gnomon
   1.0992s   

     Total   1.0996s
```

And

```
~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.8960s   

     Total   0.8984s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.8859s   

     Total   0.8863s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.9031s   

     Total   0.9035s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.9078s   

     Total   0.9083s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.8880s   

     Total   0.8884s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.8945s   

     Total   0.8951s

~/$ php b.php | gnomon
   0.8891s   

     Total   0.8896s

~/$ php test.php | gnomon
   0.8843s   

     Total   0.8847s
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, to be honest. The way I see, and based on what you have showed, it seems that b.php is actually faster than a.php, and not the other way around... :/

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first solution, php has to figure out what index must be used to set the new value and check if we are going to update existed element or add a new one.

In `b.php` new element is **always** put on the end of the array, the additional check of index is not required. This is basically how [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) works.